# Java s2s connect to https with p12 certificate and basic authorization

Tags: java, https, certificate, basic-authentication, p12

I try to implement on Java class which will connect to https server by using p12 certificate and 'Basic Authorization'. Can you please outline how to combine the both things including installing p12 cert?

**Updated**. Below is class which I use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        clientStore.load(new FileInputStream("d:\\certs\\api\\xx.p12"), "W*53as_G".toCharArray());

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(clientStore, "W*53as_G".toCharArray());
        KeyManager[] kms = kmf.getKeyManagers();

        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        trustStore.load(new FileInputStream("c:\\jdk1.8.0_51\\jre\\lib\\security\\cacerts"), "changeit".toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(trustStore);
        TrustManager[] tms = tmf.getTrustManagers();

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(kms, tms, new SecureRandom());

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        URL url = new URL("https://apis2s.ee/test");

        HttpsURLConnection urlConn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encode("andrey:pass_1".getBytes()));
        urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConn.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Pragma", "no-cache");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-length", Integer.toString("id=1288210&ip=127.0.0.1".length()));

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(urlConn.getResponseCode())
                .append(" ")
                .append(urlConn.getResponseMessage())
                .append("\n");

        System.out.println(builder);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

**Result is**

*SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target*

And with SSL debug

```
%% Invalidated: [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
pool-2-thread-1, SEND TLSv1 ALERT: fatal, description = certificate_unknown
pool-2-thread-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 01 00 02 02 2E .......
pool-2-thread-1, called closeSocket()
pool-2-thread-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 

sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification
```

Also I installed p12 cert. And the command
    *keytool -list -v -keystore c:\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\security\cacerts*
shows the cert. info:

---

```
Alias name: 1
Creation date: 28.02.2017
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 2
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=xx, O=APIs2s Sandbox Api
Issuer: CN=apis2s.ee
Serial number: 12
Valid from: Thu Feb 23 18:57:05 CST 2017 until: Fri Feb 23 18:57:05 CST 2018
Certificate fingerprints:
MD5:  E0:E0:1E:8F:09:R3:82:6C:D9:A0:7C:FD:B3:D7:7B:76
SHA1: A0:8A:87:03:7A:14:CD:3A:C6:48:4B:98:8C:89:EK:EB:73:B7:BC:BD
SHA256:          31:1B:2E:98:66:8C:F3:53:6C:FA:4E:BC:48:67:C1:DE:02:4D:71:E8:46:CE:2B:7C:B1:9F:EA    :86:69:D6:97:15    Signature algorithm name: MD5withRSA
Version: 1
Certificate[2]:
Owner: CN=apis2s.ee
Issuer: CN=apis2s.ee
Serial number: bc7428f41765c74e
Valid from: Fri Jun 24 14:52:01 CST 2016 until: Sat Jun 24 14:52:01 CST 2017
Certificate fingerprints:
MD5:  21:F3:46:A8:30:B2:1B:D6:0C:2D:E6:2F:4F:4F:8G:B    SHA1: 1C:F0:FE:4E:94:70:5E:6E:2C:5D:E6:B1:24:77:2H:0F:72:DB:F6:01
SHA256:     51:14:82:5B:80:63:57:5B:B7:6B:CB:C9:EC:FB:C3:96:07:89:A0:4E:B5:51:B7:6D:34:08:CA    :B4:B3:2F:E6
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 89 A1 81 25 17 41 EB E6   DD 7A B6 D2 23 2E 4B 40  ...%.A...z..#.K@
0010: 54 50 58 58                                        TXXX
]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483646
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 89 A2 81 25 17 41 EB E6   DD 7A B6 D2 23 2E 4B 40  ...%.A...z..#.K@
0010: 54 51 58 58                                        TXXX
]
]

*******************************************
```

Comment: Please provide your code and show what problem you have. The question is too broad right now

Comment: I added my code above.

Comment: You need to include in cacerts the root CA of the SSL server certificate in `https://apis2s.ee`, not the private key. Basic Authorization seems ok

Comment: I imported the root CA from the https://apis2s.ee by using browser and saved it in .cer file. Then I imported it

Comment: keytool -import -alias ca -file d:\certs\api\xx.cer -keystore c:\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\security\cacerts -storepass changeit
But result is the same - exception SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: %% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2

Comment: This is what I got when ran the code with -Djavax.net.debug=all

Answer (score 0):

Finally the issue was resolved by asking the server apis2s.ee team to provide the valid root CA cert. After they sent it I imported it by using the command

keytool -import -alias ca -file d:\certs\api\api\Serv_CA_SSL.cer -keystore c:\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\security\cacerts -storepass changeit

And everything is worked fine (without any restarts). I slightly changed the result class to show the server output `

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        clientStore.load(new FileInputStream("d:\\certs\\api\\xx.p12"), "W*53as_G".toCharArray());

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(clientStore, "W*53as_G".toCharArray());
        KeyManager[] kms = kmf.getKeyManagers();

        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        trustStore.load(new FileInputStream("c:\\jdk1.8.0_51\\jre\\lib\\security\\cacerts"), "changeit".toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(trustStore);
        TrustManager[] tms = tmf.getTrustManagers();

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(kms, tms, new SecureRandom());

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        URL url = new URL("https://apis2s.ee/test");

        HttpsURLConnection urlConn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encode("andrey:pass_1".getBytes()));
        urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConn.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Pragma", "no-cache");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-length", Integer.toString("id=1288210&ip=127.0.0.1".length()));

        urlConn.setDoOutput( true );
        urlConn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( jsonParams.length() ));
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
        out.print("id=1288210&ip=127.0.0.1");
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int responseCode = urlConn.getResponseCode();
        builder.append(responseCode)
                .append(" ")
                .append(urlConn.getResponseMessage())
                .append("\n");

        InputStream res = urlConn.getInputStream();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(res);
        String responseStr = "";
        while(in.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = in.nextLine();
            responseStr+=s;
        }
        System.out.println(builder);
        System.out.println("responseStr: " + responseStr);
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`

Thanks to **pedrofb** for reviewing the code and the suggestion.